# Does WP-CLI support updating multiple options via a single command?

Tags: wp-cli

I'm looking for a way to update multiple options via a single update command. The documentation only suggests the following usage:

`wp option update <key> <new_value>`

Does WP-CLI accept multiple key value pairs or a JSON or some other file containing multiple option keys and their new values?

Answer (score 1):

WP CLI's `option update` command only accepts one key per call, but you can use other commands to handle updating multiple keys in sequence. The [command page in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/#examples) has some examples.

> ```
> # Update one option on multiple sites using xargs.
> $ wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I {} sh -c 'wp --url={} option update my_option my_value'
> ```

In this example, [`xargs`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=xargs%20-n1%20-I%20%7B%7D%20sh%20-c%20%27%27) is used to build commands based on input.

Depending on your data structure, you should be able to use xargs and some wp cli commands in combination to achieve the result you're looking for.